# Different classes seem to interfere with each other

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am **in the process of developing some code to create a *`"grid layout"`*** and everything seems to be ok, at least at first glance with each individual class working as expected.

When I mix the classes though, namely put a different class in each row, things get quite confusing as **the classes seemingly interfere with each other** while they shouldn't *(except if I'm missing something)*.

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s41z31m4/) and a snippet to illustrate my problem the best possible.

**What could be causing this issue and how can I possibly fix it?**

**Note**: If you try removing some of the **`div`** elements you will notice that when not mixed they are aligned perfectly.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
}
.grid-x2 {
  width: 47.5%;
}
.grid-x3 {
  width: 30%;
}
.grid-x4 {
  width: 21.25%;
}
.grid-x5 {
  width: 16%;
}
.grid-x2:nth-of-type(2n + 1),
.grid-x3:nth-of-type(3n + 1),
.grid-x4:nth-of-type(4n + 1),
.grid-x5:nth-of-type(5n + 1) {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.grid-x3:nth-of-type(3n + 2),
.grid-x4:not(:nth-of-type(4n)):not(:nth-of-type(4n + 1)),
.grid-x5:not(:nth-of-type(5n)):not(:nth-of-type(5n + 1)) {
  margin-left: calc(2.5% - 4px);
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.grid-x2:nth-of-type(2n),
.grid-x3:nth-of-type(3n),
.grid-x4:nth-of-type(4n),
.grid-x5:nth-of-type(5n) {
  margin-left: calc(2.5% - 4px);
}
.grid-x2:nth-last-of-type(n + 3),
.grid-x3:nth-last-of-type(n + 4),
.grid-x4:nth-last-of-type(n + 5),
.grid-x5:nth-last-of-type(n + 6) {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.grid-x2,
.grid-x3,
.grid-x4,
.grid-x5 {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 25px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't HTML tables made for this?  If you are looking for a responsive grid, have you heard of [flexbox](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/), or of the many UI libraries that offer them, bootstrap, skeleton, MDL?  Why recreate the wheel?

Comment: I don't want any dependencies.

Comment: Flexbox is baked into CSS.

Comment: I'm talking about Bootstrap.

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with *grids* is that each row should be a self contained.

The main problem here being the margins. The `:nth-of-type(..)` works on the node type so it counts all divs under the same container (*it does not reset each time you change the class*).

Something like the following

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
}
.grid-x2 {
  width: 47.5%;
}
.grid-x3 {
  width: 30%;
}
.grid-x4 {
  width: 21.25%;
}
.grid-x5 {
  width: 16%;
}
.grid-x2:nth-of-type(2n + 1),
.grid-x3:nth-of-type(3n + 1),
.grid-x4:nth-of-type(4n + 1),
.grid-x5:nth-of-type(5n + 1) {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.grid-x3:nth-of-type(3n + 2),
.grid-x4:not(:nth-of-type(4n)):not(:nth-of-type(4n + 1)),
.grid-x5:not(:nth-of-type(5n)):not(:nth-of-type(5n + 1)) {
  margin-left: calc(2.5% - 4px);
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.grid-x2:nth-of-type(2n),
.grid-x3:nth-of-type(3n),
.grid-x4:nth-of-type(4n),
.grid-x5:nth-of-type(5n) {
  margin-left: calc(2.5% - 4px);
}
.grid-x2:nth-last-of-type(n + 3),
.grid-x3:nth-last-of-type(n + 4),
.grid-x4:nth-last-of-type(n + 5),
.grid-x5:nth-last-of-type(n + 6) {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.grid-x2,
.grid-x3,
.grid-x4,
.grid-x5 {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x3" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x4" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="grid-x5" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
```

---

The alternative would be to use the grid items just for the sizing (*without margins*) and use `box-sizing:border-box` and `paddings` to create the spacing. But his would require inner elements for the actual styling.

---

The latest (*and best on modern browsers*) would be to use the flexbox.
(see https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. **`Flexbox`** is still not as widely supported as I'd like, so I'm going to stick to my way for now :)